# What is the chance of rolling a die and getting the number six three times at exactly 10 rolls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> What is the chance of rolling a die and getting the number six three times at exactly 10 rolls?

I was asked this question in my statistic class. I thought the way to do this was $(1/6)^3 \times (5/6)^7$, because that is getting six 3 times and not getting it 7 times. However, that's wrong, I figured that it's because that $(1/6)^3$ would be getting 6 three times in a row. 
Could you explain how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You're nearly right. You've found the probability that the first three are 6 and the remaining seven are not 6. For example, you haven't taken account of $6111616111$.

Now, there are $\binom{10}{3}$ possible ways we could have got three 6s, so you need to multiply your answer by $\binom{10}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve computed the probability of rolling six three times and some other number seven times *in that order*. You also need to account for all of the other ways in which three sixes can come up in ten rolls. The binomial distribution is called for here. If we let $X$ be the number of times a six is rolled, then $$
P(X=3)={10\choose 3}\left(\frac16\right)^3\left(\frac56\right)^7.
$$ As you can see, there’s an extra factor of ${10\choose3}$ that you missed.